# Return boolean from Ruby controller to Ajax call

Tags: ruby, ajax, json, boolean, return

I'm trying to return a boolean from the following action to Ajax with the help of JSON:

**CONTROLLER**

```
get "#{$INDEX_BASE_URL}/login" do
  user_id = params[:user_id]

  if ToConfigureUser.check_existence(user_id)
    data = {:bool => 'true'}.to_json
    return data
  else
    data = {:bool => 'false'}.to_json
    return data
  end 
end
```

I'm using JSON but I am not even sure if that's the best practice.

Here's the Ajax:

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax(url,{
        datatype: "json",
        contenType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "GET",
        data:{
            'user_id' : user_id
        },
        success: function(data){                
            if(data.bool == "true")
            {
                alert("True");
            }   
            else
            {
                alert("False");
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Something went wrong");
        }
    });
```

My Ajax always alerts "False" even when the method "check_existence" returns true. Probably because my JSON is not constructed well. How can I return a boolean from the Ruby controller to Ajax? It does not necessarily have to be JSON, if there are better ways of doing it let me know please.

Comment: You have to use something like `render :json => { bool: <VALUE> }` instead of return.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Now I get the error "ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..4)" for the render method

Comment: I'm confused by your `get "#{$INDEX_BASE_URL}/login" do` part. I would think your controller should define a `def login` which renders the json, and in your AJAX your do a request to `"/login"`, which should be routed to that controller action. I think you are not doing it right, perhaps [this example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data) can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Changed **:bool** to **'bool'**

**CONTROLLER**

```
get "#{$INDEX_BASE_URL}/login" do
  user_id = params[:user_id]

  if ToConfigureUser.check_existence(user_id)
   {'bool' => 'true'}.to_json
  else
   {'bool' => 'false'}.to_json
  end 
end
```

I changed nothing to the Ajax code.

Answer (score 1):

The content type may not be set correctly as you have a missing t in contentType

Comment: I changed it but sadly that wasn't the problem, thanks anyway